# How to have desktop-mode restore only the <n> most recently used buffers

Tags: desktop, session

I currently have in my config:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(setq desktop-restore-eager 10)
```

Which on startup, will eagerly restore 10 buffers, and then when Emacs is idle,
restore all the others.

Is there a way I can tell Emacs "I want you to restore the most recently used 10
buffers, and then don't restore any others"?

Right now it seems like the options are either eagerly restoring every buffer,
or eagerly restoring a subset and then lazily restoring every other buffer.